# java convert one optional type to another optional type

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have to convert an `Optional<EmployeeModel>` object to `Optional<EmployeeDto>` and I am looking for some better/cleaner options than the below two.

**Option1:**

```
public Optional<EmployeeDto> findById(String employeeId){
    Optional<EmployeeModel> employeeModel = employeeService.findById(employeeId);
    return Optional.ofNullable(toEmployeeDto(toEmployeeDto.orElse(null)));
}
private EmployeeDto toEmployeeDto(EmployeeModel employeeModel) {
    if(employeeModel != null) {//We need this because orElse passes null
        //return EmployeeDto (convert EmployeeModel to dto)
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Option2:**

```
public Optional<EmployeeDto> findById(String employeeId){
    Optional<EmployeeModel> employeeModel = employeeService.findById(employeeId);
    if(employeeModel.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.of(toEmployeeDto(employeeModel.get()));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
private EmployeeDto toEmployeeDto(EmployeeModel employeeModel) {
    //isPresent()check already done so no null checks
    //return EmployeeDto (convert EmployeeModel to dto)
}
```

I can't use `Optional.map()` directly as `EmployeeModel` object can be null (i.e., `null` wrapped by `Optional`) from the `employeeService`. Also, I was just checking source code for `map()` method inside `Optional` class which does the below check:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
```

In short, my question is that can we pass `null` objects to `Optional`'s `map()` method? If yes, why does the `Objects.requireNonNull()` check in the source code?

Comment: Option1 is DRY if for example there is also something like `findBySomeOtherAttribute(String someValue)`.  If it spans classes then the if/else could be extracted to a Factory class.

Comment: If `employeeService.findById` returns an `Optional` type, and then returns `null`, not `Optional.empty`, then `findById` is seriously flawed and needs to be fixed. The entire point of using `Optional` is that you never return `null`.

Comment: @Andreas [Seconded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953120/java-convert-one-optional-type-to-another-optional-type#comment92814718_52953432)

Comment: What's your point about `Objects.requireNonNull(mapper)`? Of course you can't call `map()` without supplying a mapping function.

Comment: *"why does the `Objects.requireNonNull()` check in the source code?"* Because the *mapping function* must be supplied. The null check is not checking the **object** *(field `value` stored in the `Optional`)*, it's checking the **mapping function** *(parameter to `map` method)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method:

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an `Optional` describing the result. Otherwise return an empty `Optional`.

```
public Optional<EmployeeDto> findById(String employeeId){
    Optional<EmployeeModel> employeeModel = employeeService.findById(employeeId);
    return employeeModel.map(this::toEmployeeDto);
}
private EmployeeDto toEmployeeDto(EmployeeModel employeeModel) {
    //employeeModel will not be null, so:
    //return EmployeeDto (convert EmployeeModel to dto)
}
```

Comment: what if `employeeModel` in itself is null? [shouldn't that the first thing to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953432/1746118)?

Comment: @nullpointer If `employeeService.findById` returns an `Optional` type, and then returns `null`, not `Optional.empty`, then `findById` is seriously flawed and needs to be fixed. The entire point of using `Optional` is that you never return `null`.

Comment: @Andreas: my `employeeService' returns `Optional` type only, not `null`.

Comment: @developer Then call `map` as shown here. I don't understand why your question says you cannot use `map`, since this scenario is *exactly* the purpose of `map`.

Comment: AFAIK, `Optional map()` does a check `Objects.requireNonNull()` i.e., we should pass not `null` objects only.

Comment: @developer The `map` method (see [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#l210)) does a null check of the `mapper` parameter, to ensure that a **mapping function** is supplied. It does not do a null check of the *wrapped object* (`EmployeeModel`), because, as you can see in the source code, it does a `isPresent()` check for that.